# Is OpenCV C API outdated?

Tags: c, opencv

I am trying to use OpenCV in Raspberry Pi (embedded system) so I need the OpenCV C API source code so that I can compile it and use it.

After some search I found that C API was designed in OpenCV 1.x. Now it is supported for backward compatibility only. It is deprecated and may be removed in the future.

OpenCV has C [documentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/index.html) but I failed to get the source code.

So is OpenCV C API outdated or I can download the older version's source code ?

Comment: C++ is in every sense best when using OpenCV. I strongly recommend you to code in C++ for OpenCV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the installation guide here:
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide

There is just one package for OpenCV, which does include bindings for C. However, I don't think C++ speed versus C speed should be a problem on the Raspberry Pi, so just use C++.

Answer (score 9):

OpenCV C API is part of newer OpenCV releases as well.

However OpenCV internals are C++ in OpenCV 2.0 and later. So you cannot compile newer OpenCV without C++ support.

Comment: Yep, C API is the way to go :)

Answer (score 2):

Quoted from the [website](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Welcome) for the current version of OpenCV:

> OpenCV is released under a BSD license, it is free for both academic and commercial use. It has C++, **C**, Python and soon Java interfaces running on Windows, Linux, Android and Mac.

You can find sample C programs that ship with opencv in the `samples/c` folder in your installation or at their [github site](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/master/samples/c).